# Can I reverse a payment and re-pay with a different debit/credit card?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, payment, chargeback

Generally speaking regarding most major merchants.

I accidentally paid for something at a grocery store using a card I did not intend to use.

Would it be reasonable to return to the store with the receipts and ask them to reverse the payment and let me pay again with a new card of my choice?

I know it may depend, but just wondering if I should attempt this or if it is not possible to do.

Comment: A small grocery chain in my area would certainly do it- But they'd do it in the opposite order. They'd charge your new card first, then issue a refund on the original. Call ahead and ask to speak with the front-end office (typically where you would get money orders or ask for a normal refund). . . Good luck if it's a big chain, though. Managers have no power.

Comment: Why does it matter? Was it someone else's card?

Comment: 'Why does it matter' - you may have accidentally used a corporate rather than a personal card, you may want to keep a card with a full credit limit on it for emergencies, you may not have automatic payment setup on the card used and do not want to configure it.

Comment: How many items is it? Does this store typically do returns?

Comment: It's not clear why this question carries a [tag:chargeback] tag.  DO NOT try to use a chargeback in this scenario, it can only create trouble.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's quite clear why this question has a chargeback tag: the OP doesn't understand that the term "chargeback" has a specific meaning in the CC industry.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of an imposition. Not only will the store have to do the work of processing the additional transactions, but depending on their payment processor, they likely will incur additional fees. If it would be a significant problem for you to have the payment on the original card, go ahead and ask, but if it's just a mild preference (for instance, because you would have gotten 1% more rewards on a different card), I wouldn't do it. Ultimately, it is up to the store, and they have the option of refusing, but it's still taking advantage of their generosity a bit.

Regarding your "chargeback" tag, you DEFINITELY should not accomplish this through a chargeback. The word "refund" refers to a return of your money processed through the merchant. "Chargeback" refers to a return of money processed through the credit card network's fraud policies. Doing a chargeback means hefty fees for the merchant (even if it's not upheld), and harms their relationship with the other parties (their bank, the credit card network, your bank). Furthermore, doing a chargeback without valid reason is fraud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can certainly reverse that payment by requesting them. It's possible as I had a similar experience a few months back and the owner of the store obliged my request in a very professional manner.